# Selecting a Spinner Item to change the text within a textview?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-spinner

I need a little help with this conversion application for Android.
So I have a Spinner populated with these items:

```
 <string name="action_settings">Settings</string><string-array name="ConversionItems">
         <item >Miles to Kilometers</item>
         <item >Kilometers to Miles</item>
         <item >Inches to Centimeters</item>
         <item >Centimeters to Inches</item>
 </string-array>
```

and this is some code in my MainActivity

```
> conversionspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new
> OnItemSelectedListener() {
>       @Override
>       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
>               long id) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>           
>       }
> 
>       @Override
>       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>           return;
>       }
>     }
```

What I want to know is how would I change the text of a textview when a specific item is selected. For example if "Miles to Kilometers" was selected, `textview1` would show "Miles" and `textview2` would show "Kilometers". I'm new to android programming and programming in general, so simple solutions would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

```
    final String CONDITION_1 = "Kilometers";
    final String CONDITION_2 = "Miles";

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    int units = 10;

    private void updateText() {
         String spinnerState = conversionspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();


         if (spinnerState.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
             textView1.setText("");

         } else if (spinnerState.equalsIgnoreCase(CONDITION_1)){
             //do appropriate unit conversion:
             units = units * (8/5);
             textView1.setText(String.valueOf(units) + spinnerState);

         } else if (spinnerState.equalsIgnoreCase(CONDITION_2)) { 
             units = units * (5/8);
             textView1.setText(String.valueOf(units) + spinnerState);
         }
    }

conversionspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          updateText();

   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
conversionspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           //position will tell you which position is selected
           // in your array  index 0 - <item >Miles to Kilometers</item>
           //                index 1 - <item >Kilometers to Miles</item>
           //                index 2 - <item >Inches to Centimeters</item>
           //                index 3 - <item >Centimeters to Inches</item>

            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    textView1.settext("Miles");
                    textView2.settext("Kilometers");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    textView1.settext("Kilometer");
                    textView2.settext("Miles");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    textView1.settext("Inches");
                    textView2.settext("Centimeter");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    textView1.settext("Centimeter");
                    textView2.settext("Inches");
                    break;
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }

        });
```

Hope that helps!